# Dart server works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Dartium

Tags: dart, dartium

I’m new to Dart and I’m going through the server tutorial (https://dart-lang.github.io/server/codelab/). For some reason, the final application is working fine when accessed from the Chrome browser (Windows, Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)) and Firefox (47.0.2), but not in Dartium (=Chromium, Version 45.0.2454.104). When requested from Dartium, the server provides the html page, but it is static. The Dart code behind it (e.g. `web/piratebadge.dart`) doesn’t seem to execute at all.

However, if I run a simple client-based application (like https://webdev.dartlang.org/codelabs/angular_components) and serve it using `pub serve`, it works fine both in Dartium and in Chrome.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Please provide more details. Do you get any error message? What exactly is happening in Dartium? What URL did you try to open? Does the browser console show any error message?

Comment: @Guenter: Thanks to your response, I got a step further: The pub build does not copy the .dart files into the build directory, but just the compiled .js file. Dartium tries to execute the .dart natively (as opposed to other browsers, which execute JavaScript) and that file is not found (404). However, even when I copy it manually it doesn't help, because it relies on many dependencies which are still missing. I guess I could manually identify, copy, and rename them all, but there should be an automated way.

Comment: You can use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_to_js_script_rewriter to get rid of that 404, but it shouldn't cause any issue except the output in the browser console. For Dartium you should use `pub serve`. Dartium is not supposed to be used for production, this is why dart files are not copied by `pub build`